How would a person become a rabbi around 1 CE?
Given the general illiteracy, the lack of public libraries, the high cost of Torah copies and writing materials, how would a person become a rabbi in 1 CE?
Given the costs and reading/writing requisites it looks like it's a path only for sons of well-off families, living in a major city.
I have read Israel Finkelstein and Bart Ehrman books, which deal mostly with literacy but doesn't explore education.

R. Akiva was a poor illiterate shepherd... Hillel couldn't afford admission to the academy... both were first century rabbis and are pillars upon which Judaism stands. When there's a will, there's a way.

בית שמאי says your argument, see https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_DeRabbi_Natan.2.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

"A different tradition narrates that, at the age of 40, Akiva attended the academy of his native town, Lod, presided over by Eliezer ben Hurcanus." So, 1) there was an academy in 2) a small town. How many others academy? At what age people enter? How many people studied there? Was it like the Qumran monastery?

Scholarship was very limited and becoming a rabbi was more challenging but not impossible. Those who had the means and the talent to become a rabbi were able to.

Finkelstein wrote about Jewish literacy in the Roman period? Doesn't seem up his alley. Can you cite where he discussed this?

@Harel13. Not the roman period, right. He talk about literacy pre-exile. He made passing mentions in his many videos available in Albright Live, Kedem, lectures and books (The Bible Unearthed, The quest for historical Israel),  when talking about ostracas, seals, and other archeology findings. The pre-exile is well covered, but I don't have any information for the period period post-exile, until Bart Ehrman mentioning literacy levels around 30 CE in Misquoting Jesus, and Jesus Interrupted. And I'm just trying to figure out the plausible literacy level for common people.

Thanks for the references.

@CandidMoe is literacy your main concern? There seem to be many theories floating around that exactly around the time period you mention, literacy in the Jewish community skyrocketed (partly through the illiterate becoming assimilated) over the average gentile population. I have seen a few but I am not expert enough to sort through speculation vs. evidence on this issue, but just wanted to point it out as it is quite a famous idea. Post temple, Jews had a largely literal (male, but females were above average too) population that encouraged education and study of the Torah and its preservation.

@RabbiKaii I think that rabbis education is a good proxy for literacy among general population. If Rabbi Akiva was able to learn to read (if I understand correctly) while working as a lumberjack in a small village, that means that literacy was within the reach of ordinary people.

A useful source for this topic is Babylonian Talmud tractate Bava Batra 21a which states that the high priest Yehoshua ben Gamla instituted schools around Judea. I think some think there may have been two high priests by this name, but both lived ca. the end of the 1st century BCE or the 1st century CE.

"Be careful with the children of paupers, for from them Torah will come forth" (N'darim 81a).

In theory literacy wasn't really necessary, as the oral Torah wasn't written down. (Of course, they needed a knowledge of the written Torah as well, but that's at least theoretically memorisable as well

@Loani But a rabbi must study the Torah. How well can he do it without reading?

In the year one common era even if books would have been easily available it would have made little difference in relation to becoming a Rabbi and Jewish Education. At that point in time, on principle, almost nothing had been written down anyway.
This was seventy years before the Beis Hamikdash was destroyed, and about two hundred years before the Mishna was written down. It was forbidden to write a public record of the Oral Law. Being that  almost everything was being learned by memory anyhow the lack of or easy availability of books would have had little bearing on studying to become a rabbi
